# calling tkinter progressbar and passing percent complete

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a status/progress bar that shows how many web pages are left to scrape.  I am getting lost on how to pass the # of pages between the modules.  I think I am making a mistake by calling the tkinter window class.  Any help on how to call this module and pass the pg/pages variables would be greatly appreciated.

Module getting page count:

```
from ProgressBar import StatusWindow

pages = 25
class crawler:
    def get_pagecount():

        for eachPage in range(1,pages):               
            pg = eachPage
            Complete = '{:.0%}'.format(pg/pages)
            print(Complete) 
            StatusWindow(pages,pg)  """<== How do I call the progress bar and pass these variables?"""
if __name__=='__main__':
    crawler.get_pagecount()
```

ProgressBar:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

backRGB = '#e5e5e5'
root = Tk()
root.configure(bg=backRGB)
root.configure()

class StatusWindow(Frame,ToDo,Done): """<==Probably not where I should be calling and passing variables?"""
    def __init__(self,master = None):
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.master = master
        self.init_window()
        self.grid()
        self.tk_setPalette(background='#e5e5e5', foreground = '#001030',activeBackground='#001030',activeForeground='white')
        ToDo = 10
        Done = 5
        self.Progress_Bar(ToDo,Done)  

    def Progress_Bar(self,ToDo,Done):
        progressbar = ttk.Progressbar(root, orient = HORIZONTAL, length = 300)
        progressbar.grid(row=9, column = 0)
        progressbar.config(mode = 'determinate', maximum = ToDo, value = Done)

    def init_window(self):
        self.master.title("Program Status")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        menu = Menu(self.master)
        self.master.config(menu=menu)
        text = Text(self.master)     

app = StatusWindow(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You probably want to create an instance of `StatusWindow` like ` status_window = StatusWindow(arguements)` and then have a loop that monitors the page status like a `IntVar()` or `StringVar()` and then when the value changes have that call an update function that will update the value to the status bar. You will need to make the status bar a class attribute to be able to update it.

Comment: @Mike-SMT - Thanks for your response!   I am relatively new to Python and still thoroughly confused.  Where do I create the instance of StatusWindow?  Isn't that what I am doing with `app = StatusWindow(root)`?  The loop to monitor page status - can this be included in the for loop `for eachPage in range(1,pages):`?